# shinydashboard: strange rendering when using uiOutput() for body

Tags: r, shiny, rendering, data-science, shinydashboard

I want my dahsboardbody to change depending on a choice make in the sidebar. However, I have a problem with the resulting rendering of the body as shown below:

[wrong rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5G0G.png)

The box has width = 12 and hence should cover the whole Row like this:

[correct rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsKGa.png)

Here is the code I am using:

```html
body1 <- dashboardBody(
     box(title = "test1", width = 12)
)

body2 <- dashboardBody(
  box(title = "test2", width = 12)
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Choose", tabName = "test",
             radioButtons("choice", label = NULL, choices = c("body1", "body2"))
    )
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(uiOutput("body"))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(),
  sidebar = sidebar,
  body = body1
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$body <- renderUI({
    if(input$choice == "body1") {
      body1
    }
    else {
      body2
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Resizing the window or open it in the browser doesn't help. What am I missing?

I am using R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23) with shinydashboard_0.7.0 and shiny_1.1.0.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Your code work perfectly for me, it just like correct rendering .

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `body` argument of `dashboardPage()` to be as follows:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(),
  sidebar = sidebar,
  body = dashboardBody(uiOutput("body"))
)
```

In addition drop the `dashboardBody()` wrapper from the `body1` and `body2` variables:

```
body1 <- box(title = "test1", width = 12)
body2 <- box(title = "test2", width = 12)
```

It will solve the dynamic body issue and might solve your rendering issue as well.